# pseudo inverse of a finite-to-one continuous map and measurability

Tags: measure-theory, descriptive-set-theory

Given that $\pi: X \to Y$ is a continuous onto map between compact metric spaces such that the fiber $\pi^{-1}(y)$ is a finite subset of $X$ for all $y$, is the map $y \mapsto \pi^{-1}(y)$ guaranteed to behave in a measurable way? For example, is it guaranteed that $y \mapsto |\pi^{-1}(y)|$ is Borel measurable, and that for each Borel measurable $A \subset X$, the subset  $\{ y \in Y : A \cap \pi^{-1}(y) \neq \emptyset \}$ is Borel measurable?

For any concrete enough class of maps satisfying the assumption, there always seems to be a way to prove the conclusion just for that class, so I could not find any particular counter-example.

**Remark 1.** It is easy to think of a zig zag like map from the interval onto itself such that $y \mapsto |\pi^{-1}(y)|$ is neither upper nor lower semi-continuous. So the idea that $\{y \in Y:  |\pi^{-1}(y)| \ge k\}$ might always be a closed subset does not work for establishing the partial conclusion that $y \mapsto |\pi^{-1}(y)|$ is measurable.

**Remark 2.** The measure theoretical counterpart (where measures are involved) has positive answer, but that implies nothing about the original problem. The measure theoretical counterpart is: given a measure preserving map $\pi: (X, \mu) \to (Y, \nu)$ between two Lebesgue spaces (i.e. standard probability space) such that the disintegration $\mu_y$ is supported on a finite subset of $X$ for $\nu$-a.e. $y$, then the map $y \mapsto \bar{\pi}(y)$ where $\bar{\pi}(y) := \{ x \in X: \mu_y(x) > 0 \}$, which is $\nu$-a.e. well defined (unlike the map $y \mapsto \pi^{-1}(y)$ which is not well defined), is a measurable map in some sense. For example, $\{ y \in Y : A \cap \bar{\pi}(y) \neq \emptyset \}$ is measurable for any measurable $A \subset X$. If $A$ in that expression runs over elements of appropriate finite partitions of $X$, then the map $y \mapsto \bar{\pi}(y)$ corresponds a map from $Y$ to the set of binary sequences, and the latter map is measurable, which we may take as the meaning of the former map being measurable.

(Update) **Remark 3.** The counterpart for the case where only Y (and not X) is a probability space also has a positive answer: if $\pi: X \to Y$ is a Borel-measurable (not necessarily onto) map from a Polish space $X$ to another Polish space $Y$ and if $\nu$ is a probability measure on $Y$, then it is easy to check that $\{y \in Y: |\pi^{-1}{y}| \ge k\}$ and $\{y \in Y:  A \cap \pi^{-1}{y} \ne \emptyset \}$ are analytic sets and hence $\nu$-measurable. This might be useful for studying measures in $\pi_*^{-1}(\nu)$.

Comment: @900sit-upsaday Yes I mean Borel measurable. Edited to clarify the question.

Comment: Remark 3 seems wrong. Consider the Cantor set $\mathcal C\subseteq[0,1]$, and a nonmeasurable set $\mathcal N\subseteq[0,1]$ such that there's a bijection $f\colon\mathcal C\to\mathcal N$. We extend $f$ to $[0,1]$ such that $f(x)=x+1$ for all $x\not\in\mathcal C$. Note that the totality of $y$ such that $\#f^{-1}y=1$ isn't measurable. I doubt we should assume that $\pi$ is continuous.

Comment: @FrankScience A subset of Y is called $\nu$-measurable if it belongs to the completion of the Borel sigma-algebra with respect to the measure $\nu$. Remark 3 concerns $\nu$-measurability.

Comment: Okay, and could you please explicate a sketch of the proof of this fact? It seems to me that, the well-known technique of Banach indicatrix only works for continuous functions between Euclidean spaces, which is still not a piece of cake to me. I am not familiar with such stuff as analytic sets, etc.

Comment: @FrankScience For example, the set $\{y\in Y: |\pi^{-1}y| \ge k\}$ is an analytic subset of $Y$ under the requirement that $\pi$ be Borel-measurable, as it is the projection (to $Y$) of a Borel subset in $X^k \times Y$, namely, the subset consisting of all $(x_1,x_2,\dots, x_k, y) \in X^k \times Y$ for which $\pi(x_i) = y$ for all $1 \le i \le k$ and $x_i \neq x_j$ for all $1 \le i < j \le k$. It is a known result in descriptive set theory that any analytic subset is universally measurable, but I am not familiar with its proof.

Comment: Nice, thanks! You can attach the proof to the original post.